# Base class needs to return auto-type based on derived specific type

Tags: c++, generics, base-class

I would like to make a generic base class for storing the same Interface class in an array. However, the generic class should return a type specific variable based on its derivative.

I tried different design approaches with templates and type deductions... Also tried to store the actual value in a nested class container.

I think, I need a different approach instead of solving this... But I don't know what will work for me.
Any designed patterns that can tackle this approach ?

```
// Base Class

class IAlpha
{
public:
    virtual auto Get() = 0;
};


// Derived Class

template< typename T >
class Alpha : public IAlpha
{
    T x;
public:
    Alpha(T _x) : x(_x) { }
    auto Get() ->decltype(x) override { return x; }
};


// Main

    IAlpha *i = new Alpha<int>(1);
    IAlpha *d = new Alpha<double>(1.0);


    int x = i->Get();
    double y = d->Get();


The error I get at IAlpha::Get()
"Function with deduced return type cannot be virtual"

I understand the problem, and it can be resolved for example by

    virtual auto Get()->decltype("TYPE") = 0;

But the problem is the Interface does not know the TYPE and it should not to maintain it generic....

Note,
`std::variant` & `std::any` are unfortunately no options in my application.
```

Comment: What about making the interface a template class?

Comment: You can make the function template based and specialize the template in your derived classes.

Comment: Your goal is not inline with the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: _@Ron_ You maybe also interested in the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, when I make it a template class, It cannot be stored in a array anymore as the interface are not the same anymore.

Comment: _@RonSalm_ Well that's an indicator that you have a serious design flaw in your class architecture. May be it's just missing another level of indirection. You should read the link @StoryTeller posted.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I will try the curiously recurring template pattern. maybe I can find a suitable solution in this

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Yeah.... I already see that the interface becomes a template. Therefore I cannot store it anymore as a generic type in a array.. so that won't work unfortunately

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I agree , I admit there is a design issue... but not sure how to solve it. Yet :)

Comment: @RonSalm _"but not sure how to solve it. Yet :)"_ Well, as mentioned introducing more levels of indirection could be a way to go if you need to decouple from the _templated types_ (i.e. generic parameters).

Comment: @Hemil, virtual functions like Get in the interface cannot be template.

Comment: @RonSalm What do you do with your `int` and `double` after you got them? That would be the first place I'd look. If you can generalize that part you might not need to know the type contained in `IAlpha` at all.

Comment: @super, all IAlpha's will be stored in a  (Singleton) ParameterManager. During  initialising, every class in my project can get the parameter they need.

Comment: @RonSalm Sounds like this "ParameterManager" should be part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not ideal... but It will do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>

template< typename T >
class Param;

class IParam
{
protected:

public:

    template< typename T>
    const T& Get()
    {
        return static_cast< Param<T>* >(this)->Read();
    };
};


template< typename T >
class Param:
    public IParam
{
    T *x;
public:
    Param()
    {
        x = new T();
    }

    void Set( T _v)
    {
        *x = _v;
    }

    const T& Read()
    {
        return *x;
    }
};

// This vector will be a Singleton Parameter Manager
std::vector<IParam*> mParameters;

class Alpha
{
private:
    Param<int> *param;
public:
    Alpha()
    {
        param = new Param<int>();
        mParameters.push_back( param );
    }

    void Set()
    {
        param->Set(1);
    }
};

int main ()
{
    std::cout << "Starting Sandbox" << "\n";

    Alpha *a = new Alpha();

    // Attach to the Alpha parameter
    const int& i = mParameters[0]->Get<int>();

    // Print 0
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    a->Set();

    // Print 1
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is a combination of the proposal of Hemil and the suggestion of πάνταῥεῖ,